# FFMPEG profile-level-id size is invalid

Tags: java, c++, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I'm trying to record a RTSP streaming from `JVC KY-PZ 100`.
So for that i'm using ffmpeg with some parameters like segmentation, hls, ts, m3u8 etc ...
i'm always getting an error `The profile-level-id field size is invalid (41)` and `Error parsing AU headers`

This is the output of `FFPROBE` to debug the RTSP

```
ffprobe -loglevel verbose  -i rtsp://jvc:0000@192.168.0.124:554/stream

ffprobe version 4.2.2 Copyright (c) 2007-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.2.2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags='-I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-13.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/include -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-13.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin' --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-videotoolbox --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
[tcp @ 0x7fa99ee001c0] Starting connection attempt to 192.168.0.124 port 554
[tcp @ 0x7fa99ee001c0] Successfully connected to 192.168.0.124 port 554
[rtsp @ 0x7fa99f807200] SDP:
v=0
o=- 1581949225269357 1 IN IP4 192.168.0.124
s=KY-PZ100
i=KY-PZ100
t=0 0
a=tool:LIVE555 Streaming Media v2013.10.03
a=type:broadcast
a=control:*
a=range:npt=0-
a=x-qt-text-nam:KY-PZ100
a=x-qt-text-inf:KY-PZ100
m=audio 0 RTP/AVP 96
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
b=AS:96
a=rtpmap:96 mpeg4-generic/48000/2
a=fmtp:96 streamtype=5;profile-level-id=41;mode=AAC-hbr;sizelength=13;indexlength=3;indexdeltalength=3;config=1190
a=control:track1
m=video 0 RTP/AVP 97
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
b=AS:1500
a=rtpmap:97 H264/90000
a=fmtp:97 packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=4D401E;sprop-parameter-sets=Z01AHqtgUBf8uAqQEBAUAAAPpAADqYOlABksDcoUQDuLFIs=,aM48gA==
a=control:track2

[rtsp @ 0x7fa99f807200] The profile-level-id field size is invalid (41)
[rtsp @ 0x7fa99f807200] setting jitter buffer size to 500
    Last message repeated 1 times
[rtsp @ 0x7fa99f807200] Error parsing AU headers
    Last message repeated 4 times
[h264 @ 0x7fa9a0806600] Reinit context to 640x368, pix_fmt: yuv420p
[rtsp @ 0x7fa99f807200] Error parsing AU headers
    Last message repeated 235 times
[rtsp @ 0x7fa99f807200] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5005000 microseconds st:1
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://jvc:0000@192.168.0.124:554/stream':
  Metadata:
    title           : KY-PZ100
    comment         : KY-PZ100
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.066733, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Stream #0:1: Video: h264 (Main), 1 reference frame, yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive, left), 640x360 (640x368) [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The verification of SDP `fmtp` integer parameter ranges was fixed in [c29d81e73641d0f58e6f058a095e18b99769dac1](https://git.ffmpeg.org/gitweb/ffmpeg.git/commit/c29d81e) but the patch is probably not released yet.

Compile `ffmpeg` from the latest git sources and retry.